# Design Pattern Question : (i.e. Service A - > if fail call Service B. Service B -> if fail, call Service C etc..)

Tags: java, design-patterns

I'm attempting to clean up some inherited code.

Here is the flow of the service :

I have a REST Call to Service A, if a valid response is received then response is returned to sender and the process is complete.  However, if Service A fails ( data is not found 404 ).  I want to call Service B.

The question is is there a recommended pattern for this type of activity?  Is a pattern overkill?  I'd love to hear peoples thoughts on this.

NOTE: Reason why I'm leaning toward a pattern is because in the future we might call more services in this type of situation.  (i.e. Service A if fail, Service B if fail, Service C etc..)

Comment: Chain of responsability https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain-of-responsibility_pattern

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.